# Is it proper way to change domino name?

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

Is it okay to change a name of domino server without removing from a clustered group? I'm thinking it will affect the clients cluster.ncf that will not be updated. Or do I need- remove first from cluster group then change name then rejoin. Hoping for your immediate response. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for "renaming" a server as there is for a user. If you need a new server name, then you have to register a new server, adjust the settings to be the same as the old one, add this mew server to the cluster and then "rename" the old server by exchanging server id and everything that belongs to it in the notes.ini.

Take care: this will not work, if you use daos and the daos repository is encrypted (what it is by default), as the new server will not be able to read the attachments after "rename" anymore.

Comment: I've checked we do not use daos based on server configuration. What if i directly rename the server name? Adjust ACL and configurations..will the user be updated? I think your answer is great, it will be much better to create server id and add to cluster. This is the safest approach.

Comment: Again: there is no way to rename a server. Changing the name in the server document does not change the name in the server id, therefor it is useless... It is simply not possible...

Comment: But you can do this: 1. register new server & save the id file; 2. delete new server doc; 3. copy old server doc and config doc; 4. edit the copy of old server doc & config doc to match the new name; 5. shut down the server, swap the id files (be sure to save the old one!), and restart; 6. after verifying everything is okay, delete the original server doc and config doc. This is just a way of cheating to make sure that all settings are accurately duplicated.

Comment: What about the certificates? Just editing the name will render the copy of the document useless... Nevertheless copying the documents might help with making sure, the settings are identical. Just don't forget to change the certificates as well...

Comment: Yes, good point. If you're doing anything that relies on the certificates in the server doc, you'd better get those right!

Comment: How do I swap the domino server ID with the new one?

Comment: @rhsatrhs thanks i'm following your step by step, its great. I think I cannot change the host name of the server in Windows. Domino Console do not resolve and produce error.

Comment: If you swap the IDs on the server, make sure that NO database is encrypted (that's a feature controlled per DB). The ID from the server is used to encrypt server DBs (if you use the server DB encryption feature), so if you swap only the ID and leave the files (e.g. the *.nsf) in place the DB will be no longer readable. I would prefer to create a new server and then replicate all the content to it instead of swapping the server ID only. Otherwise you need to swap the ID back to the old one if you see that a DB open will cause issues because of the encryption.

Comment: But how do I swap the server ID? I cannot find it..don't worry the setup are clustered and replicated..

Comment: There is a file in the data directory of your server, that is called "server.id" or "yourservername.id". This id is referenced in at least two places in the notes.ini of the server. To swap the id you need to copy the new id and edit the notes.ini. In addition you need to edit dcontroller.ini and dconsole.ini and some other places. If you do not change hostname and ip address, then probably none of your clients will successfully connect to your server after exchange. If you do not even know, where to finde the id: ask someone to help you. This otherwise will fail!!!!

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect it would be another config file either way I successfully update the server name with all your help. Thank you very much :)